# Anonymous users authorized to access register.aspx but being re-directed to login page

Tags: asp.net, authorization

Trying to restrict anonymous users to login.aspx, register.aspx and Site.css files and authenticated to have access to whole site.
Currently anonymous can access login.aspx and Site.css as styles appearing correctly. However when I click on register.aspx link I get redirected to login.aspx page.

Below my web.config in web root. There are no other web.configs in directory structure. I don't know if I should be looking anywhere else (I know WSAT can sometimes hold rules but not sure if superseded by root Web.config).

Was just thinking login and register files reference a master page would this need explicit authorization as well? Although wouldn't explain why login works for anonymous but register doesn't.

Thanks for your help! Anthony.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="************"
         connectionString="Data Source=**********; Initial Catalog=************; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Site.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Website/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="***********" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="**********" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="***********" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check in Fiddler or in `Network` tab in browser's dev tools, which requests return 401 code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the paths to include ~/Website, the same as your forms authentication login location. You wont need the login page specifed as by default it allows access as it is the LoginUrl in your formsauthentication setup.

```
  <location path="~/Website/Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="~/Website/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it made no difference. Also, since I then switched back to previous code my styles are no longer coming through - not sure if there is a caching issue with development webserver or chrome browser or does asp.net sometimes cache web.configs?

Comment: What is the exact url you navigate to in the browser for the Register page and the login page, including http://?

Comment: http://localhost:4842/Website/Login.aspx              http://localhost:4842/Website/Register.aspx              but then when I click on Register.aspx link I get this returned in address bar: http://localhost:4842/Website/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebsite%2fRegister.aspx

Comment: Strange. I got a local example running with your config values fine. Download this and see if you can get to the about page. Css will be broken. http://www.wduffy.co.uk/website1.zip

Comment: Also try changing the <allow users="?"/> to <allow users="*"/> for the register page.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing to * no difference. Downloaded website, do I need to just paste these into an existing site in VS or is there a missing .csproj or .sln file. Also I tend to use web application projects. That wouldn't make any difference would it?

Comment: Something else I noticed is I have login.aspx and register.aspx in same folder as content files rather than in account subdirectory like in your solution. Also you have a separate web.config in account subdirectory maybe I should try replicating your directory structure and web.config file structure

Comment: Yea that file is a web site not a web application. You should be able to just choose File > Open Web Site and choose the folder. Then run the site as you would a web app.

Comment: Yes thanks your example website works for me. I'll see if it's something to do with the fact you have your register.aspx and login.aspx in a separate 'account' folder which itself contains a separate web.config. But this doesn't explain why the about.aspx page is accessible as well to anonymous users. Can you tell me why .css is broken, how can I fix this - same issue on my website. Thanks for your help. Cheers, Anthony.

Comment: The css file is broken because it is going through authorizarion. You have the following in your web.config <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>. This tells IIS to pass all requests though asp.nets registered modules, not just .aspx pages.

Comment: Hi I put the allow elements in a separate Web.config at the level of website folder rather than in Web.config at root and it worked! 

I put in the elements for styles and  images otherwise they were not being picked up for anonymous users.

Thanks again for your help - if I hadn't seen your solution with the separate web.config I don't think I would have thought about this!

Comment: Try my solution below

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow only anonymous users:
(pay attention to the added deny node after the allow!

```
<location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```